# Monosocial font library for python django project not working in live environment

Tags: python, html, css, django, fonts

I have installed the mono-social font using pip in django framework. Then after the installation of the package I have included the url to use these fonts in base.html like this

```
<link href="{% static 'social_media_links/css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="{% static 'social_media_links/css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

And I have used the fonts in this ways:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' backend='linkedin-oauth2' %}"  style="font-size:30px" class="symbol">&#xe252</a>
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}" style="font-size:30px" class="symbol">&#xe286
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' backend='google-oauth2'%}" style="font-size:30px" class="symbol">&#xe239
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}" style="font-size:30px" class="symbol">&#xe227
```

The font works fine on local but when the project is deployed using wsgi file the fonts appears as weird characters.

Please help me out with this problem

Comment: Have you installed the correct package on your production server too?

Comment: This problem i solved myself, no one answered on stackoverflow.